# How to use default values for filters in a mongo selector?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, selector

I am trying to apply filters to a mongo find query. The idea is that if a filter has value the mongo selector will limit what is being returned, but if no filter is specified (the filter has a null or default value) it should not limit the query. I know how to get the filters to work if a filter was specified, but I am unsure how to make sure it returns unfiltered if no filter was specified. How can I get the find query to return all documents in the collection if the filters are unspecified or at their default values?

FYI: I am using this in a Meteor project and will make the filters a Session variable to make what is returned dynamic.

Example Collection:

```
/* example documents in SampleCollection

{ name: "sample1", fieldA: "foo", fieldB: "foo" }
{ name: "sample2", fieldA: "foo", fieldB: "bar" }
{ name: "sample3", fieldA: "bar", fieldB: "foo" }
{ name: "sample4", fieldA: "bar", fieldB: "bar" }

*/
```

Example JS Code:

```
var filters = {
    fieldA: null,
    fieldB: null
};

var getFieldASelector = function () {
    if (filters.fieldA) {
        return { $eq: fieldA };
    } else {
        /* fieldA has a falsey value which is the default
            and therefore should not limit the find query */
        // not sure what to return here
        return {};
    };
};

var getFieldBSelector = function () {
    if (filters.fieldB) {
        return { $eq: fieldB };
    } else {
        /* fieldB has a falsey value which is the default
            and therefore should not limit the find query */
        // not sure what to return here
        return {};
    };
};

var results = SampleCollection.find({
    fieldA: getFieldASelector(),
    fieldB: getFieldBSelector()
});
```

In this example `results` should return all four documents. If `filter = { fieldA: "foo", fieldB: null };` then `results` should return the documents sample1 and sample2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every document has both keys, you can just `return {$ne:null}`. If you want to make if work if the key exists, but its value is null, you can also `return {$exists:true}`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you create a `selector` object and populate it according to the given filters. Though I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking for.

```
function getResults(filter){
    var selector = {};

    // what this does is filters aways keys with non-truthy values
    Object.keys(filter).reduce(function (prev, curr){
        var val = filter[curr];
        if (!!val)
          prev[curr] = filter[curr];
        return prev;
    }, selector);

    return SampleCollection.find(selector);
}
```

What out for unintended behaviour when you actually want to filter a field with a non-truthy values such as `0` or an empty string.

Comment: This might work, I will test it with Meteor's Session variables to see if it works when dynamically changing the filters object. What I was looking for was providing a comparison (example: {$eq:"foo"}) in SampleCollection.find({fieldA:{}}) that returns all documents regardless of what fieldA is. That way when the filter.fieldA is truthy, it will actual limit the query. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess you could change `prev[curr] = filter[curr];` to `prev[curr] = {$eq:filter[curr]};`